# Copy DLLS from sub-directory to Bin\debug on build

Tags: .net, dll, build-process

I have looked at several answers to this but it does not fit my needs.

I am including quite a few external non-net DLLs.

at the moment I add a new item to my solution and I set 'copy if newer'.

I think this looks messy (due to the number of DLLs) so I put them in a sub-directory in my project solution.

I then added this to my app.config file:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="OpenCV" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

This, on build, creates a folder 'OpenCV' in my bin\debug folder and all the DLLs are copied into opencv.

I do not want that.

I want them to be placed directly into my bin\debug folder.

Can it be done easily?

Comment: Why don't you add them to a new project and reference that new project from your actual project? Can't you use nuget packages?

Comment: rene, that's a cool idea.  I would like to see if I can do this without adding a new project but if not will happily do as you suggested. many thanks

Comment: OpenCV is unmanaged code, .NET config nor MSBuild are going to help.  You are pretty dead-set on shooting your leg off for a very minor inconvenience.  Never mess with DLL Hell.

Comment: Hi, i am just a control freak :).  OK, point taken.  Thanks